# Bind array with same ID

Tags: php, arrays

I have an PHP array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 21
        [header_image] => logo.png
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 21
        [menu1] => About
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 22
        [menu2] => Speaker
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 22
        [menu3] => Agenda
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 22
        [menu4] => Venue
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 23
        [menu5] => Hotel
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 23
        [menu6] => Sponsors
    )
)
```

I want array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 21
        [header_image] => logo.png
        [menu1] => About
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 22
        [menu2] => Speaker
        [menu3] => Agenda
        [menu4] => Venue
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [option_id] => 23
        [menu5] => Hotel
        [menu6] => Sponsors
    )

   )
```

I want to bind array having same option_id.
 How can I achieve this?

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: You don't specify how the array is generated initially - if it is from a database call then adjust your logic that produces the array from the recordset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the array with `foreach`

```
<?php
$output = array();
if (! empty($arr)) {
  foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    if (! empty($elem)) {
      foreach ($elem as $k => $v) {
        $output[$elem['option_id']][$k] = $v;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works..Thanks..I just found where I am wrong..Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you leave empty in `[$k]`?